# Use div like iframe with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, persistent

I'd like to implement a persistent div on the right of my website like facebook contact list.

The simple solution would be to use iframe... But iframe are not really used now. 
So, is there any way to simply add jquery plugin to have persistent div without changing all link on my website.

I think it can even be used, for embedding a persistent audio player, to continue listening music while navigating the website.

Comment: You can't listen to music while navigating if you are not using ajax

Comment: iframe are not really used now? Wrong! Have you looked at the html of a facebook or twitter page?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I was talking about frame no iframe

Answer (score 2):

An iFrame is the exact right answer in this case. While they've fallen out of favor as a standard design element, they still have plenty of valid uses.